# How to load bundle of images in a scrollview with horrizondal scrolling in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I have an iPhone application in which i need to load a bulk of images (ie around 50),which has a small rect like (little above thumbnail) containing 3 in each row with 4 columns in one page, and i need to scroll horizontally to load the next 12 images and so on. Also i need to show the page number under it as 1,2 etc.[image: like the attached image]

Can any body guide me in the right direction to achieve this in a scroll view ?i am really in a mess ,how to add imageview to a scrollview like this ,also each image view has its own buttons also.

Comment: for horizontal table view plz check this url..http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2

Comment: Where are the images coming from ?

Comment: from my array.which is created from my bundle

Comment: So, you have to create a view controller which takes this array in its initializer. Then create a custom view which displays your images in whatever way you see fit. You create an array of these custom views and use the code I wrote in my answer below to provide scrolling between them. Hope that's clear.

Answer (score 0):

The way i would tackle this problem goes as follows: (I am not going to provide many details as they are dependent on your particular needs and requirements).

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;//assuming the scrollView is connected in a xib file

-(id)initWithImages:(NSArray*)images;//that could be whatever format you get your images(UIImage, urls to download, file names or custom views. Here we assume that the array contains instances of UIImage)

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *images;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat pageWidth;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int currentPage;

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(id)initWithImages:(NSArray*)images{

    self = [super init];

    if(self){

        self.images = images;

    }
    return self;

}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.scrollView setDelegate:self];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width*self.imageURLsArray.count,
                                               self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    [self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

    self.pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;


    for(int i = 0; i < self.images.count; i++){

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width*i,
                                                                              self.scrollView.frame.origin.y,
                                                                              self.scrollView.frame.size.width,
                                                                              self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        imageView.image = [self.images objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];

    }

}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    int page = floor(scrollView.contentOffset.x - self.pageWidth/2)/self.pageWidth + 1;
    if(self.currentPage != page){
        NSLog(@"Scrolled to new page: %d", page);
        self.currentPage = page;
//do additional things based on the fact that you have scrolled to a new page (like changing the page number)
    }
 }
@end
```

Comment: i need 12 images to be displayed in one page,then scroll to right and then load the next like that i need.i suspect ur code will not do that

Comment: Just change the view controller's initializer to instead of taking an array of images as a parameter to take an array of your custom view(containing 12 images). The code I have written is going to do to the scrolling part only. Make sure you separate the image loading functionality from scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Use  UItableview create  custom cell with two imageviews on it and load that custom cell to cell for indexpath then create an nsarray and pass the image names into that array and then convert that image into data format for eg

nsdata *data = [NSdata dataWithcontents of url [array object at index:indexpath.row]];
cell.imageview.image = [uiimage imagewithdata:data];
  for this you should know to create custom cells.