# Add some images to ScrollView from some URLs

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, imageview

I want to add 3 images from 3 URLs in ScrollView so how could I do?
Please give me a good tutorial or some explanations!

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151721/how-to-load-bundle-of-images-in-a-scrollview-with-horrizondal-scrolling-in-iphon/15155403#15155403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "AsyncImageView" class files it will load image synchronically.

please refer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15377082/1713478

in this answer this method call for tableview you can use in for loop and place imageview in scrollview
for putting images vertically

```
int y = 10; 
for (int i = 0; i < (number of images); i++)
{
   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X, y, width, height)];

   NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: (image link for i number)];
   AsyncImageView *async = [[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
   [async loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
  [imageView addSubview:async];
  [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
  y = y+height+10;
}
```

Comment: how it use for ScrollView ?

Comment: use for loop and use code from "UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X, y, width, height)];"

Comment: to [cell addSubview:imageView]; and also replace cell to scrollview

Comment: why use AsyncImageView in ScrollView ? it load only one time,if we use cell means it load more?

Comment: Please explain clearly about what is (image link for i number) of your code?

Comment: this is image link of your image if i = 0 then first image link and i=1 then second image link.

Comment: when i clean memory, cache will be also clear i dont want to clear cache how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can user [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) for gridView kind of display and [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to load remote images OR how to layout them on a scroll view?
1.
`UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"..."]]];`
Wrap it all in `dispatch_async` or put it in `NSOperation` to make sure you don't block the main thread.
2.
You can try to use `UIPageViewController` instead of a `UIScrollView`