# UIScrollView paging loads subviews slower than scroll, how to cancel gestures, delay,..?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, gesture, scroll-paging

When scrolling fast through a scrollview, im not sure if the content is not loaded fast enough or drawing is skipped since i generate new subviews from checking scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: (is there a better method ?) Speedy scrolling is not required! - i just want to solve the problems it causes.

Longer explanation:
I have a scrollview with large content size and paging enabled. For a given page, three subviews are added with frames origin at -1, 0, +1 times framesize (so the middle frame is visible, the others are next and previous page). Frame -1 and +1 are ImageViews, Frame 0 is another UIScrollView with its own ImageView subview. They are not subclassed.

For performance reasons, my approach is to check if the scrolling moves forward or backward, and only load the new image, since the two others are already loaded i store them, e.g. "UIImage *tempImg1 = previousPageImageView.image" and take them from there once the subviews have been added.

Now fast scrolling causes the new image not to appear, but worse, the program gets confused at which index it should be at and crahses. I tried it with small pictures but same problem.

The user does not necessarily be allowed to scroll fast, it would probably be sufficient to ignore further swipe gestures once a page move has been initiated until the loading has finished.

Thanks much for ideas.

page load:

```
-(void)loadSVforPage:(int)page
{
    int nextSVpage = page +1;
    int previousSVpage = page -1;
    int numberOfAssets = assets.count;

    ALAsset *displayAsset;
    ALAssetRepresentation *assetRep;
    CGFloat SVwidth = scrollLarge.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat SVheight = scrollLarge.frame.size.height;

    UIImage *tempImg1;
    UIImage *tempImg2;
    UIImage *tempImg3;
    UIImage *displayed;


    if (page != currentpage)
    {

        // if moves are +1 or -1 use temp images, else load all
        if (page == currentpage +1) // moving forward
        {
            //NSLog(@"page+");
            tempImg1 = nextSVImg;   // the former "next", which now becomes current
            tempImg3 = currentSVImg;  // the former "current", which now becomes previous

            if ((page+1 >=0) && (page+1 <= assets.count-1))  
            {
                displayAsset = [assets objectAtIndex:page+1];  // the "new next" image 
                assetRep = [displayAsset defaultRepresentation];
                tempImg2 = [ImageProcessing fullSizeImageForAssetRepresentation:assetRep];
            }
        }
        else if (page == currentpage -1) // moving backwards

        ....
        ....
        ....

        // LOAD PAGE+1 

        if (nextSVpage <= numberOfAssets-1)
        {
            displayed = tempImg2;

                nextSVImg = displayed;  // store the image for future scrolls

                CGRect frame = CGRectMake(nextSVpage * SVwidth, 0, SVwidth, SVheight);

                //old code adding UIImageViews
                //------------------------------
                //nextScrollImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
                //[completeScrollableImageView addSubview:nextScrollImageView];
                //nextScrollImageView.image = displayed;

                // new code with subclassed UIView and image in drawRect
                //-------------------------------
                scrollUIViewNext = [[scrollviewImage alloc]initWithFrame:frame andImage:displayed];
                [completeScrollableImageView addSubview:scrollUIViewNext];

                ....
                ....
                ....
```

trigger load:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.tag == 0)  // the base SV
    {
        int pageNumber = floor(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width + 0.5);//+1;
        if (pageNumber != currentpage)
        {
            //NSLog(@"moved from current %i to %i",currentpage,pageNumber);
            [self loadSVforPage:pageNumber];
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Try to generate your subviews in `scrollViewDidScroll`. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151721/how-to-load-bundle-of-images-in-a-scrollview-with-horrizondal-scrolling-in-iphon/15155403#15155403

Comment: tried that before with same problem, but apparently changed the rest of code meanwhile so now it works... stupid me. Thank you for helping out, still a lot to learn..

Comment: Maybe you have had another error somewhere. Glad to help. I guess it doesnt make sense to create subviews in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating. Btw if you add some of your code, I would give a proper answer so we stick to the stack overflow concepts.

Comment: I recall the reason for not using scrollViewDidScroll, as it has severly more lag / stuttering than scrollViewDidEndDecelerating, so that is now the new problem, which i guess is common but how can i solve it ? subclassing UIView instead of using UIImageViews did not help at all (read that somewhere)

Comment: The reason you have more lag is its loading more views. The reason you had missing views with `didEndDecelerating` is because that is only called when they stop scrolling. A possible happy medium since you said you didn't care that it looked bad and just didn't want it to get confused is to keep track of page count in `didScroll` and load in `didEndDecelerating`. But again, this is going to leave blank sections until the user slows down their scrolling.

Comment: This does help the with the pages, neat. Btw i did not say i dont care if it looks bad, i said its not important to have superfast scrolling. Images not appearing actually IS bad. Photos app apparently has no problem speeding thru my hi-res images, whats the magic ?

Comment: @pe60t0 your comment was correct if you wish to post it as answer, ty